# ¿Como puedo hacer acción de dos elementos superpuestos y que cada uno haga una acción?

Tags: javascript

A ver si alguien me puede ayudar porque llevo una semana atascado y no consigo hacerlo. Soy un poco novato.
El caso es que quiero que al hacer mouseover en cualquier imagen, la imagen que le he dado click se ponga en scale 1.2 y se quite la barra negra de la imagen(está puesto css como elemento absoluto). He conseguido el mouseover en las imagenes y mouseout en las imagenes para que se vuelva a su scale 1 mediante el for in, pero no se como hacer para que también se quite la barra negra de la imagen que se ha seleccionado. Muchísimas gracias.
[image: Este es el html]
[image: Código Js]

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí
Imagen del código 
[image: Imagen de la página web]

Comment: Deberías poner el código en formato texto y no en imágenes, de otra forma será difícil obtener respuestas.

Comment: Necesitas obligatoriamente que se haga con javascript?

Comment: Muchas gracias chicos. Lo siento pero es que soy un poco novato y estoy aprendiendo Javascript por eso me gustaría hacerlo con Js en lugar de CSS3. Roger tienes razón, la próxima vez lo haré así. Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema espero lo puedas resolver de la siguiente manera.
Hice uso de la propiedad `overflow: hidden` para ocultar todo lo que salga de nuestro elemento padre también de la posición `absolute` para colocar el elemento que contiene el texto en la parte inferior del elemento padre, agregas transiciones para darle un efecto más atractivo y mediante javascript solo le colocas un valor negativo al bottom para que se oculte tu texto.

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('IMG');
for (let image in images) {
    images[image].onmouseover = function() {
        this.style.scale = 1.2;
        this.nextElementSibling.style.bottom = '-150px';
    }
    images[image].onmouseout= function() {
        this.style.scale = 1;
        this.nextElementSibling.style.bottom = 0;
    }
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.imagen {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    height: 350px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.imagen img{
    width: 100%;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.texto-imagen {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0 20px;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: rgba(30, 30, 30, 0.8);
    color: orangered;

    transition: bottom 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="imagen">
        <img src="https://blog.ida.cl/wp-content/uploads/sites/5/2016/11/UI-UX-DEVELOPMENT-Brillmindz.jpg" alt="imagen">
        <div class="texto-imagen">
            <h1>Texto de prueba</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Espero mi ejemplo te ayude con tu problema

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Me ha servido mucho. El único problema que tengo es que al hacer mouseover el método scale hace crecer un poco la imagen(pone mas width y mas height) y no se ve como el ejemplo que has puesto tu(que la imagen se acerca, no crece de width y height). ¿Porque puede ser posible? Muchisimas gracias y lo siento pero estoy aprendiendo.Un saludo!

Comment: Ya lo tengo. Me faltaba la propiedad overflow: hidden. Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Que bueno que te fue de ayuda. éxito!